# Need help trying to enter 1 or 2 digits in a textbox before focusing to next textbox

Tags: asp.net

Hi i am trying to enter 1 or 2 digits in a text box in asp.net c#. I want to focus in the next text box.
Here is my code but it throws an error that the textbox1 is being accessed from a different thread that it was created.

private void textBox19_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Thread t = new Thread(() => {
Thread.Sleep(2000);
textBox1.Focus();`
}
);
t.Start();
}

Comment: and the reason for the thread and sleep in this event is what?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first up, you need to grasp and understand the concept of a round trip.

next up, the text changed event does NOT fire until the user is finished typing in that text box and hits TAB. So you can't really do key press processing with code behind.

When you hit tab, then a post back occures. This is is the ALL IMPORTANT start of the round trip. If you do not with absolute certaintity grasp this concpet, then all your fortay into asp.net pages will be lost, and you will forevermore be 100% lost. you must, absolute must grasp this concpet.

So Our round trip:

A button is clicked, or a event is triggered for htat control (keypress processing will not work - it is WHEN the user hits tab).

So, button click or tab on that control.

```
Post back occures
The WHOLE web page travels up to the server.
When we say whole page, we mean ALL of the browser HTML, all of the whole page
This includes all controls, all graphics, all HTML - the whole deal
Now the page is at the server.
The asp.net processes the market.
THEN your code behind runs. At this point your event code runs
In your event code, you can say modify a value of a control.

Now:
Then the WHOLE PAGE travels back to the browser and is refresed and displald.
The page is now sitting back on the client side browser.
So as the user types. Clicks into a text box etc.? The browser is allowing this.
The server is not being talked to (unless you trigger another post-back (round trip).
```

So, as the user is typing in that text box?
As the user is editing that text box?
This is ALL occurring browser side. You are NOT talking to the server and those round trips are NOT occuring.

So you can't say put some timer on the text box and look/check/see/hope for a change in what your code sees. None of that code is going to run untill that page post back occures and the round trip starts.

A round trip is expensive, and in general is NOT appropiate for keypress processing. If you were to setup a full page post back for EACH keypress, then each key press would be JUST like a submit button - the whole page has to travel back up to the server.

So, now that you grasp the above?
Well, then you can't loop/pool/test the value of a text box with code behind on the server You can ONLY see/use/check/modify/play with controls on the form AFTER the WHOLE WEB PAGE has been sent up to the server. Thus single key press processing is not practial.

Ok, so what can we do here?

Most simple is to use client side code. Simply check the length of the text box, and if it 2 characters, then set the focus to another control.

So, lets drop a text box on a form, and we can use this markup for this to work:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"
   onkeyup="mykeycheck()" >
</asp:TextBox>
<script>
 function mykeycheck() {
     vTextBox = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox3.ClientID %>');
     if (vTextBox.value.length == 2) {
        document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').focus();
     }
  }
</script>
```

So, now, our focus will jump to Textbox1, and we don't have ANY server side code.

Can we "some how" do single key press checking and run server side code?

Well, yes, you can. But then again, that huge large round trip process will occur.

We can however, I suppose introduce a update-panel. This would suggest that the text box is OUTSIDE of the up-date panel, and we could say for example display the results of the text box, and run code behind for each keypress. I can post the code and how to do this, but in general, having a full round trip for each keypress is quite much the same idea as having a submit button for every key you press - quite heavy.

So, I can't stress how absolute important it is to keep in mind that to run/use/have code behind interact with the web page, it can only do so during that "small" time when the page is been posted up to the server, and your code runs, and then the WHOLE page is now re-send back to the browser side. And you code behind can only see/touch/modify/use the controls on that page WHILE the page is up on the server during that round trip. But it not going to stay up there very long - and after all your code runs, the WHOLE page is now send back down client side. And this would also mean that even simple things like your cursor position in the text box would be lost. You can VERY much think of the round trip process VERY much like as if you just had hit the refresh key.

So, you not use nor need any code behind in the text changed event. However, DO keep in mind that when we use the above client side JavaScript, that when we change the focus, if you do still have a server side text changed event wired up, (and postback = true for that text box), then the server side code WILL run, and a post back will occur. Since we really don't need nor want a postback to occur, then of course we will remove that text changed code stub, and turn off the post-back setting for that text box.

Comment: Thanks Albert the following code works for 2 digits then focus moves to text box 1.But i am looking for a choice to enter 1 or 2 digits./*   var score = textBoxhcap.Text.Length >1 ;

               if (score)

               {
                   textBox1.Focus();
               }*/

Comment: Hum, not 100% clear. So if the user enters 2 digits - jump to some text box. But if they enter 1 digit, then what is to occur? You mean if I enter 1 digit, then look at my paper and before I enter the 2nd digit - it will jump without me being allowed to enter that 2nd digit after some time? (are you being paid to develop the worlds most confusing UI on this planet?). So, it not clear how you going to decide that the user wants (or not) to enter that 2nd digit. I mean, either they enter 1 digit hit tab, or they get used to enter 01 to save them the effort of having to hit tab.

Comment: Hi Albert   This is a score card where competitor can have a 5 0r 2 0r 12 and so on .

Comment: right, so for super fast data entry, they can type  in 05 and it will jump to the next text box without having to leave the keyboard. If they type in 5, how long are they to wait before it jumps? if the text box is to have 1 digit, then sure jump to the next. But if they have a choice of 1 or 2 digits, then I think it is a stretch to have some hard code delay in which they type in 1 digit and WAIT for the cursor to jump. That does not really aid rapid keyboard entry. Either they hit 5 then tab, or they enter 05 to jump to the next. Having some timed delay will only get in their way.

Comment: Yes Albert this does exactly what i want                                                             void Stop()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                textBoxhcap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () {
                   
                    textBox1.Focus();

                }));
            }
              );

            t.Start();
        }

Comment: Well if that code works and does exactly what you want, then why the question? I fail to see how that code going to work, but if it does - hey no problem! And a 2 second delay? Gee, I can type in 5+ numbers in 2 seconds - hardly saving data entry time??? I don't see how that code going to work on a web page - you need client side JavaScript to make that work - not server side code (unless this is blazer which means your .net code actually does run 100% in the browser client side).